# Error Executing Command: No matching features for odl-l2switch-switch/0 and the same for odl-dlux-applications

Tags: opendaylight

I have installed opendaylight Neon SR1 and trying to install the features odl-l2switch-switch and odl-dlux-application but it gives an error saing no matching features found 
if these features has been dropped in Neon SR1 then what are the other alternative features I can use instead of those mentioned above ?
Appreciate your help
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no alternatives for l2-switch and dlux. You could use an earlier release.